# Display tooltip of Item list for Sharepoint Folder

Tags: c#, javascript, sharepoint-2010

I am using SharePoint 2010 and my requirement is to show tooltip when I hover the mouse over the title column for each item. 
For Example: There is a folder named Sharepoint2010. When user places the mouse over the folder, it should display the list of items text inside that particular folder like, 123.xls, abc.doc, what ever the list it. Is there a way to do it. I am sure there is. Any help is greatly appreciated.
I am trying to get the code using Javascript or C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to accomplish this goal:

1. You can build a custom Web Part that displays the content of the list, and have direct control over every layout element of the web part. Here is a link to building web-parts, in case you need it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ee513148
2. You can use the XSLT Web Part to create custom views for your list. Not sure if it will work exactly as you like. Found another link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff630941.aspx

I suggest you build your own custom Web Part to view the list. You could even make it a reusable web-part with custom web part settings, to point to whatever document library you wish.